# Configuring SSL on nginx with proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, ssl, gunicorn

I am having problems making SSL work for a python/gunicorn based site that works perfectly fine on port 80. I am using `proxy_pass` to send traffic to upstream.

**Steps Completed so far**

1. Wildcard certificate bundle from Incommon that works on other apache
   sites copied into the machine containing nginx in `/etc/ssl`. The
   three files in the bundle are `domain.crt`, `domain.key`,
   `incommon.crt`
2. Created a chain cert called `domain.chain.crt` using `cat domain.crt incommon.crt > domain.chain.crt`
3. Set `775` permissions and same ownership as my `sites-available` config on all 4 files.
4. Created the following config under `sites-available`:

   ```
   server { 
      listen 80;
      server_name <subdom.domainname.com>;
      location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_pass https://unix:/var/www/developmentfolder/sandbox.sock;
         proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/domain.chain.crt;
         proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/domain.key;
      }
   }
   ```

**Issues**

I can't access the site now for either 80 or 443. Nginx's error log doesn't show anything nor does the log file for `gunicorn`. The syntax check for Nginx passes everytime. Is there something I am doing that's wrong here?

Nginx version is 1.10.3

Comment: what us your `proxy_params`

Comment: In the config you provided you are not listening on 443. It is also important that you let Nginx do the https and not the proxied server in the back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing things the wrong way. You say you want https to work, yet you configure port 80 to use a local socket via https protocol. I'm not even sure that can be done, but what it would accomplish is encrypt the connection between nginx and gunicorn through a file-based unix-domain socket. It would do nothing for the connection between browser and your webserver.

If all you want to do is make your site available via https, then why not follow [the official guide](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) and do more complicated things once that is working.

If you have that working and if you're serious about encrypting the connection between webserver and gunicorn, then I wouldn't use unix domain sockets, but use [SSL configuration](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#ssl) and HTTPS connection.

Comment: I have followed the official guide before, but it doesn't seem to work since there is no place to put an "intermediate certificate" in `Nginx`

Comment: Sure there is. Same way as adding CA to server in a bundle: `cat server.crt intermediate.crt root-ca.crt > bundle.crt`. Et voila. Make sure you use the right order.